# .NET Core + jQuery AJAX Request with 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: jquery, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-core-2.0

[image: PostMan post request where I am passing Access-Control-Allow-Origin, and in below screen you can see that it's successfully passing the headers.]

[image: Fiddler request Headers where you can notice Access-Control Allow-Origin is passing in headers and also it's working fine.]

With above screen I just want to let you guys know that while I am using POST man ajax call that time it working as expected but when I am trying to make the same AJAX call using jQuery it's not working at all, I means I am getting 200 ok status but all the properties on my object are empty and I am sure that is because the headers is not passing properly while making ajax call using jQuery.

I have tried many ways but not able to figure out why it's not working for me.

Below are the code which I have tried using jQUery AJAX call.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:61146/MarkAndUnmarkCountry",
            data: JSON.stringify({ obj: obj }), 
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                if (data != null) {

                }
            }, error: function (err) {
                debugger;
                console.log(err.statusText);

            }, complete: function () {
                //DropDownUiBinding();
            }
        });
```

This is me .NET CORE POST Method.

```
public class CountryController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ICountryApi _countryApi;
        public CountryController(ICountryApi countryApi)
        {
            _countryApi = countryApi;
        }


            [Route("MarkAndUnmarkCountry")]
            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<IActionResult> MarkAndUnmarkCountry([FromBody] FavoriteRequestModel obj)
            {

                var resultJson = await _countryApi.MarkCountryFavourite(obj);
                return Json(new { result = resultJson });
            }
    }
```

This is my controller and below is my startup configuration

```
 app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
                       {
                           routes.MapRoute(
                               name: "default",
                               template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                       });
```

Comment: Could you show the controller and routing configuration?

Comment: Please check above,, I have updated my question accordingly.